# Allow iframe to have access to parent's functions but not to redirection

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

Is that even possible to have both things working?

1. A script inside an iframe can call the parent window's functions.
2. That same script can't change the location of the main window.

This is inside iframe:

```js
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  parent.hide_x();
});
```

```html
<h1>iframe</h1>
<button class="button">Hide x!</button>
```

Comment: 1. Yes via postMessage 2. I don't understand what you mean, you write the script ?

Comment: @Max I write both scripts, yes. Your answer helped me a lot!